# In a pandas hist () plot with sub-histograms, how to insert titles for the x and y axes, and overall title?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I am using the pandas hist() method with the 'by' option, specifically:

```
histos=data_ok._DiffPricePercent.hist(by=input_data._Category, sharex=True, sharey=True )
```

This command produces this plot:
[image: This is the plot I am getting]

How do I add titles for respectively the x and y axes on each of the sub-histograms, or alternatively, overall? Also, how to insert an overall title for the plot?

I tried the following, but it does not go through (with error "AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'set_ylabel'"):

```
histos.set_ylabel('Fréquence')
histos.set_xlabel('Variation prix suggérée, en %')
```

Many thanks in advance for any suggestions

Comment: `hist` should return `axes` objects which can be used to set things like titles and labels. What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: I am using pandas 0.14.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you actually get is an object-type numpy array with elements in it that are the AxesSubplot instances.  Try

```
histos[0].set_xlabel('My x label 1')
histos[1].set_xlabel('My x label 2')
```

**EDIT :**
To change the format of ticks, use a Formatter:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter

maj_frm = FormatStrFormatter('%.1f')
...
histos[0].xaxis.set_major_formatter(maj_frm)
```

The documentation on tick locating and formatting can be found [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html).

Comment: i am getting error 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'ylabel'

Answer (score 0):

.plot or .hist on a pandas dataframe is likely to write a numpy array with a given size.

One way to set attributes at the level of the subplot is (assuming the numpy array plt outputted by a pandas plot is 2D):

```
    for (x,y), value in numpy.ndenumerate(plt)
      plt[x,y].set_xlabel(...)
      plt[x,y].set_xticks([...])
```

and so on.