# How do I get the x and y labels to appear when displaying more then one histogram using pandas hist() function with the by argument?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to create a series of graphs that share x and y labels. I can get the graphs to each have a label (explained well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24913661/in-a-pandas-hist-plot-with-sub-histograms-how-to-insert-titles-for-the-x-and)!), but this is not what I am looking for.

I want one label that covers the y axis of both graphs, and same for the x axis.

I've been looking at the matplotlib and pandas documentation and I was unable to find anything that addresses this issues when the using `by` argument.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4],
                   'B': [1, 7, 2, 4, 1, 4, 8, 3],
                   'C': [1, 4, 8, 3, 1, 7, 3, 4],
                   'D': [1, 2, 6, 5, 8, 3, 1, 7]},
                  index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8])

histo = df.hist(by=df['A'], sharey=True, sharex=True)
plt.ylabel('ylabel') # I assume the label is created on the 4th graph and then deleted?
plt.xlabel('xlabel') # Creates a label on the 4th graph.
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The ouput looks like this.
[image: Histograms]

Is there any way that I can create a Y Label that goes across the entire left side of the image (not each graph individually) and the same for the X Label.

As you can see, the x label only appears on the last graph created, and there is no y label.

Help?

Comment: Also see https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/11147

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way to do it indirectly using the x- and y-labels as texts. I am not aware of a direct way using `plt.xlabel` or `plt.ylabel`. When passing an axis object to `df.hist`, the `sharex` and `sharey` arguments have to be passed in `plt.subplots()`. Here you can manually control/specify the position where you want to put the labels. For example, if you think the x-label is too close to the ticks, you can use `0.5, -0.02, 'X-label'` to shift it slightly below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

f, ax  = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(8, 6), sharex=True, sharey=True)

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4],
                   'B': [1, 7, 2, 4, 1, 4, 8, 3],
                   'C': [1, 4, 8, 3, 1, 7, 3, 4],
                   'D': [1, 2, 6, 5, 8, 3, 1, 7]},
                  index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8])

histo = df.hist(by=df['A'], ax=ax)
f.text(0, 0.5, 'Y-label', ha='center', va='center', fontsize=20, rotation='vertical')
f.text(0.5, 0, 'X-label', ha='center', va='center', fontsize=20)

plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This works and is exactly what I'm looking for. I have new questions now, but I haven't looked around for the answer yet. In my code this is wrapped in a function and I could end up with 1 graph, or up to 9 graphs. Now I need to find a way for `plt.subplots()` to take a dynamic number. I keep getting a ValueError: The number of passed axes must be (odd number), the same as the output plot.

Comment: You should put plt.subplots inside the function. Without looking at the code it’s hard to say what’s going on

Comment: Basically remove the two rows associated with 'A' 4 out of the data. Run the original code on this data and you have 3 graphs now instead of 4 because you are sorting by 'A'. Run your updated code and you'll receive the error. @ Bazingaa

Comment: Ok, give me some time. Will do it after dinner

Comment: I'm sure I can find it somewhere else. If you're interested and curious I'd be glad for an answer, but don't worry about it if you're busy. You've answered the more important question already!

Comment: I didn't understand when you say "Basically remove the two rows associated with 'A' 4 out of the data.". This is A: `'A': [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4]`. What numbers should be deleted? And also, what numbers should be deleted from the B, C, D?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186500/discussion-between-christopher-james-and-bazingaa).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue with the variable number of sub-plots using something like this:

```py
cols = 3
n = len(set(df['A']))
rows = int(n / cols) + (0 if n % cols == 0 else 1)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(rows, cols)

extra = rows * cols - n

if extra:
    newaxes = []
    count = 0
    for row in range(rows):
        for col in range(cols):
            if count < n:
                newaxes.append(axes[row][col])
            else:
                axes[row][col].axis('off')
            count += 1
else:
    newaxes = axes

hist = df.hist(by=df['A'], ax=newaxes)
```